# How to move spotlight(s) relative to camera position in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I wish to have a spotlight that will move together with the camera. the following code works if I only want to keep the spotlight at the same position as the camera at all times:

```
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 200 );
pointLight.position = camera.position;
scene.add(pointLight);
```

However, how can I make it work so that the spotlight is always **in front of** the camera by a certain distance? Or generally, always in the same position relative to the position of the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add light to the camera's hierarchy.
Then light's coordinate system is relative to the camera's.
Then simply move it along the z-axis.

```
camera.add( pLight );
pLight.position = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,10);
```

Comment: Thanks! I initially figured it out that I can set the point light's position inside the render() function like this `pointlight.position.z = camera.position.z - 10` so that it keeps moving every frame, but your solution is cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Your solution also works only if the camera is looking along the negative z-axis. Putting object in hierarchy also counts for rotation of the camera. Another way would be to find forward vector of the camera, so you could write `pLight.position = camera.position + camForwardVec * distance;` .

Comment: This solution makes the apparent intensity of the light dependent on how close the camera is to the object. (But, okay, that might be something you actually want). I couldn't solve this by setting the third parameter of the PointLight to zero.

Comment: Don't forget to do scene.add(camera) too, in many situations the camera isn't already in the scene, but if you want children of the camera rendered, it'll need to be

Answer (score -1):

You could simply do:

```
point.position = camera.position
```

every time before rendering.

If you use something like OrbitControl it would look like this:

```
orbit.addEventListener('change', function () {
  render();
});

function render () {
  lights.point.position = camera.position;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Im not sure this answers my question..? How does that allow me to keep the pointlight ahead of the camera while moving? As far as I can tell this does the same thing as the code that I posted.